# What's more appropriate - concat or map?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to execute 2 promises, then pass the result of promise2 to a bunch of other rxjs operators to do a bunch of different things if promise2 resolves.  But I want promise2 to execute only if promise1 resolves.  To get this effect, should I be using something like

```
from(promise1).pipe(
map(x => promise2),
tap((x) => console.log('response from map: ', x)),
other_rxjs_ops)
  .subscribe(...)
```

If I use concat instead of map

```
concat(promise1, defer(() => promise2)).pipe(
tap(console.log('response from map: ', x)),
other_rxjs_ops))
  .subscribe(...)
```

I'm presuming what will happen is that promise1 will execute, and if it resolves, promise2 will execute, and results from both promises will then go through the other rxjs operators and be subscribed to, right?

So is my approach with map for the desired result appropriate or should I be thinking of another rxjs operator to work with in executing promise1 and promise2?  The one issue I run into when using `map` is that the console.log inside `tap` seems to execute before the promise inside `map` has resolved or errored out, and console prints the following:

```
response from map: undefined //presuming promise2 hasn't had a chance to resolve yet, which is why we're getting undefined because the promise is designed to return a string value.
```

Using concatMap instead of map addresses this issue, but I don't understand why tap behaves the way it does when used with map.  Any guidance on that would be helpful also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your 1st option

You are using `map` operator and seeing `tap` is not waiting for promise to be resolved.

So what is happening here,`map` operator doesn't subscribe inner observable so it is returning **promise object(`Promise {}`)** and will not wait to be resolved,for that `tap` operator here logging this - `response from map: Promise {}`

Any higher order mapping(`concatMap` `mergemap` `switchMap` `ExhaustMap`) subscribe the inner observable.Know more: [link1](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) | [Link2](https://www.perfomatix.com/rxjs-higher-order-mapping-angular-development-company/)

So in this `concatMap(x => promise2)` of code,`concatMap` will subscribe `promise2` and will emit data when `promise2` get resolved.

**1st option using `concatMap`**

```ts
from(promise1)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((x) => promise2),
    tap((x) => console.log('response from map: ', x))
    // other_rxjs_ops...
  )
  .subscribe();
```

In your case **source observable** which is `from(promise1`) will emit response once `promise1` is resolved.After receiving response from promise1,`concatMap` will subscribe `promise2`

One Promise can emit only one data either resolve or reject so you can use `mergeMap` or any higher order map operator also here.

So you can consider **1st option** if you need to use `promise1` response to call `promise2`.

Now coming to your **2nd option**,which is using [concat](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/concat).

So you can consider this over 1st option if `promise2` is not dependent on response of `promise1`.

Simply your requirement is to call `promise2` after completion of `promise1`

I am providing a working example,by which you can clear your doubts

```ts
import { concat, from, interval, of } from 'rxjs';
import {
  concatMap,
  exhaustMap,
  map,
  mergeMap,
  switchMap,
  take,
  tap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = interval(1000).pipe(take(5));

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Promise1 resolved!');
    // reject('Promise1 rejected!');
  }, 5000);
});

/*..............Option 1..............*/
source
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((result) => {
      console.log("Inside pipe: ",result);
      return promise1;
    })
    // concatMap(()=>promise1),
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    error: console.error,
    complete: () => console.log('Completed!'),
  });

// source.pipe(
//   tap(console.log),
//   map(()=>promise1),
// ).subscribe(console.log);

/*..............Option 2..............*/

concat(source, promise1).subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.log('Completed!'),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can use one of the [Higher-Order RxJS mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/), such as `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, or `switchMap`, to merge streams to each other.

You can try something like the following:

```js
from(promise1)
  .pipe(
    // promise2 won't be executed until the promise1 is resolved.
    concatMap((val1) => from(promise2)),
    // tap won't be executed until the promise2 is resolved.
    tap((val2) => console.log('response from promise2:', val2))
    // Other RxJS operators here...
  )
  .subscribe();
```

**Notes:**

- The `map` operator is used to transform the value to another type, and in your case, it's used to transform the `promise1` result to a `Promise`, however, it doesn't subscribe to it nor convert it to an `Observable`, so the `tap` is executed directly after transforming it, without waiting it to be resolved.
- (Optional) To be able to subscribe to the `promise1`, it should be transformed to `Observable` using `from` function.
- To subscribe to the new `Observable` it should be merged with the original `from(promise1)` one, using one of the higher-order mapping operators not using the normal `map`.

Comment: that's what I have for now.  I don't understand why `tap` doesn't wait for `map` to first finish converting `val1`, but it waits when I use `concatMap` on `val1` instead.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The `map` operator is used to transform the value to another type, and in your case, it's used to transform the `promise1` result to a`Promise` type, but it should be transformed to `Observable` to be able to subscribe to it and wait for its result (and don't move directly to the `tap` operator), so we used `from`, then to subscribe to the new `Observable` it should be merged with the original one (`from(promise1)`) using one of the higher-order mapping operators not using normal `map`.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Do you really need to use `from` for Promise2 within concatMap?  Doesn't concatMap take promises for arguments also and convert them into observables internally?

Comment: `from` is not require.Any higher order map will covert `promise` to `observable` and will subscribe it

Comment: @Amer `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom` Convert an observable to a promise by subscribing to the observable,even it's in documentation you provided.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! of course, you are right. the `lastValueFrom` & `firstValueFrom` are used to convert the `Observable` to promise, instead of deprecated `toPromise` function.

Comment: Regarding the `from`, yes, it's not required, but I prefer to convert it explicitly to `Observable` and used to do that. Anyway, thanks!